# Installing WPScan and Metasploit on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: metasploit

I installed Metasploit and all dependencies with guidance of [this webiste](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/) after that I want to install wpscan from git but when I try to run the WPScan I get this error:

> cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

But I've install the bundler and all dependencies for it and for Metasploit.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use ruby 2.0 and install the bundler for that specific version.